# header menu in wordpress not displaying all the items

Tags: wordpress, menu

im having a small problem with menu in wordpress
i cant able to place more than 60 items in the menu, It is adding but when i click save button the particular menu items are not displaying in the wordpress menu if it exceed 60 items in menu.
Im using ultimatum theme, So can you please help me out for sloving this issue 
here is my site url http://www.thetwelfthfruit.com/
in the above site in header menu after (help) i am unable to add any other menu item in the header, when i am adding menu 1 item in the middle of menu the bottom menu item (ie Help) is getting deleted.

and i have tried below code in htaccess

i have given 
php_value max_input_vars 5000

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Server Configuration using

```
<?php php_info(); ?>
```

And also Please Refer the link:

http://sevenspark.com/wordpress/menu-item-limit

I think it will help you.

Comment: but i cant find that usesful to me because im having ht access file in my server that procerss i am unable to slove the  issue so can u please slove the problem here is my ht access file                                                                                   # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_input_vars 5000
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: Set variable is proper in .htaccess. Also increase the var WP_MEMORY_LIMIT and WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT in the wp-includes\default-constants.php. Using that it increase admin and wordpress memory beacause sometimes it also create the problem. And also check max_execution_time , max_input_time, memory_limit values any of that it is small it is create the problem.

Answer (score 1):

first create php.ini file,
then copy the below code into that

```
 max_input_vars = 3000; 
 suhosin.get.max_vars = 3000;
 suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000;
 suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000;
```

save the file and that's it, the magic will be done....!!!!!!